# Julia with Gallium: `AssertionError: arg isa Expr && arg.head == :call`

Tags: debugging, julia, gallium

I follow the instructions on the [Gallium page](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl) to debug a script such as this one:

```
using Gallium
@enter a = gcd(10, 20)
```

and I get

```
ERROR: LoadError: AssertionError: arg isa Expr && arg.head == :call
Stacktrace:
 [1] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [2] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
while loading /Users/mmorin/Temp/test.jl, in expression starting on line 5
```

How can I debug the function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to debug an expression, not an assignment. In this case, remove the `a =`, as in the [GitHub example](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl), to debug the function itself:

```
using Gallium
@enter gcd(10, 20)
```

See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Keno/ASTInterpreter2.jl/issues/11).